# Live streaming with FFmpeg

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

How to use this code in python, please guide in detail i am completely new.

```
ffmpeg \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 \
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -g 20 -b:v 2500k \
-c:a aac -ar 44100 \
-threads 0 -bufsize 512k \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOURSTREAM &> stream.log
```

i tried writing it in pycharm

1. when i just pasted in the editor it gave me error as usual
2. Then i tried it writing in os.system() and subprocess.call() like this

## os.system

```
os.system(ffmpeg \)
os.system(-f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 \)
os.system(-f v4l2 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 \)
os.system(-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -g 20 -b:v 2500k\)
os.system(-c:a aac -ar 44100 \)
os.system(-threads 0 -bufsize 512k \)
os.system(-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOURSTREAM &> stream.log)
```

## subprocess.call()

```
subprocess.call(ffmpeg \)
subprocess.call(-f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 \)
subprocess.call(-f v4l2 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 \)
subprocess.call(-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -g 20 -b:v 2500k\)
subprocess.call(-c:a aac -ar 44100 \)
subprocess.call(-threads 0 -bufsize 512k \)
subprocess.call(-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOURSTREAM &> stream.log)
```

both time it gave me errors like

```
'-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-vcodec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-acodec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-f' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please guide me and if there is any other way to upload a video to youtube live stream through python please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your entire ffmpeg command into a single subprocess.call, separating the arguments into a list.

This (slightly modified) command is working for me streaming a clip to my facebook page:

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-ac", "2", "-i", "/home/ubuntu/clip.mp4", "-r", "10", "-i", "/home/ubuntu/clip.mp4", "-c:v", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-g", "20", "-b:v", "2500k", "-c:a", "aac", "-ar", "44100", "-threads", "0", "-bufsize", "512k", "-f", "flv", "rtmp://rtmp-api-dev.facebook.com:80/rtmp/10156686554299774?<my stream key>"])
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response, i am going to execute this but before that i have one more query that this command also depends on the location where ffmpeg is installed, but i have installed it using pip instruction from command line so shall i worry about the location thing?

Comment: Can you share your command which produces the error below?  Reading from file preferred.  It says deprecated pixel format.  Can you double check "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p".